# ngfor not working as expected

Tags: angular

if I do `heroes[0].name` or `heroes[1].name`, then the following code works but if I try the same with `ngFor` following code doesn't work:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <h1>{{heroes[1].name}}</h1>
  <p>Heroes:</p>
 <ul class="col-xs-12">
            <a href="" class="list-group-item clearfix" *ngFor="let hero of heroes"></a> 
            <li class="pull-left">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"> {{ hero.name }} </h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text"> {{ hero.description }} </p>
                <span class="pull-right">
                    <img src="{{ hero.imagePath }}" alt="" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 50px">
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
`
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'All of Heroes';
  heroes: Hero[] =[
    new Hero('Hero 1', 'Test',
'https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/sites/default/files/styles/recipe/public/recipe_images/recipe-image-legacy-id--488691_11.jpg'),
    new Hero('Hero 2', 'Test',  'http://media3.sailusfood.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/veg-momos-recipe.jpg')
  ];
}
```

WebPage is displayed like following, although there should be 2 `<li>` with name, description and image :

[image]

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Open your browser console, and read and post the error you get. Even better, instead of posting a screenshot of your stackblitz project, post itsURL, so that we can see by ourselves.

Comment: For a start, you shouldn't have an anchor (`<a>`) inside a `<ul>`.

Comment: Second: the ngFor is on the `<a>, so only the `<a>`is repeated, and the hero is only defined inside the `<a>`. Remove this `<a>`, and put the ngFor on the `<li>`: that(s what you want to repeat.

Comment: Thanks your inputs helped.